# What is the "process noise" (Q) parameter to a Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm teaching myself about Kalman filters; I've studied a number of videos and articles and have enough of an understanding now that I can effectively construct and use them.

However, most of what I've seen skips over the "process noise" parameter (the Q matrix) and just states things like "you can make these up".

My question is, what does "process noise" represent and, more importantly, how can I tune it for optimal filter performance? I can't seem to find any solid explanations of how "process noise" relates to the real system model in practice.